# Find expectation or lower bound of log erf

Tags: expected-value, bounds, variational-bayes

I need to find the expectation of $\log \Phi(x)=\log \left(\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}s^2)ds\right)$. (I realise this isn't quite the error function, but not sure what to call it). $x$ is normally distributed such that $x\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

I attempted to use quadrature here but the 'erf' values close to zero causes numerical issues.

If no closed form solution exists, any thoughts on a possible lower bound? I'm using a Variational Bayes method and hence why I ask for a lower bound.

Edit: I'd be much happier to use a lower bound, or an approximation than have to use sampling.

Comment: As I remember, $F_X(X) \sim Unif(0,1)$ if $X$ is a continuous r.v., where $F_X$ is the c.d.f of $X$. So, $\Phi(x) \sim Unif(0,1)$, where $x \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: That is correct but what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: Then, you are finding $E(log U)$, $U \sim U(0,1)$

Comment: @kitman0804, this only works when $X \sim N(0, 1)$ since $\Phi$ is the cdf of standard normal $N(0, 1)$ rather than of $X$ itself.

Comment: Oh sorry, I made a careless mistake

Comment: I thought (with some simple numerical experiments) there doesn't exist a unified answer for this question except when $X \sim N(0, 1)$, the value depends on $\mu \text{ and } \sigma^2$ in some complicated way if allowing both $\mu$ and $\sigma$ to change freely. Some asymptotic result may hold if fix one of them and let the other go to its extreme value.

Comment: @Zhanxiong That's correct. However, the case $\sigma\lt 1$ is qualitatively different than the case $\sigma\gt 1$.  Moreover, a good numerical quadrature routine has no problems with this.